# How do you calculate the amount of characters including spaces and numbers in a string

Tags: python

I want to find out how many characters there are in a string I've received from an input.

```
message = raw_input('Enter your message: ')
```

I know that your could do this manually through list().

```
ListMessage = list(message)
```

which would print if opted `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']` and I know that i can access each letter with message[0] to get the letter 'h'.

I would want to get the program to store each letter from the list as a string on its own from where I can access and alter.

Comment: `len(message)` will count all the characters in the string.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `I would want to get the program to store each letter from the list as a string on its own from where I can access and alter` - that's what `list(message)` **does**.  Each letter is stored as its own 1-character-long string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of a string can be obtained with the built-in function `len`:

```
len(message)
```

You can access single letters via their index:

```
>>> message[0]
'h'
>>> message[1]
'e'
```

I am not sure why you want to this but you can store a single letter with its own name:

```
var1 = message[0]
var2 = message[1]
```

Now `var1` holds `h` and `var2` `e`. Strings are immutable. Therefore, you cannot change a value of string. But you can create a new string. For example:

```
upper_var1 = var1.upper()
```

Now `upper_var1` contains `H`.

Comment: What I meant by it was that I want the program to be able to find out the amount of letters given from the input and how I could get the program to store each letter including spaces and numbers with its own accessible name.

Comment: @Arjan That is what the answer says. `len(message)` gives you amount of letters including spaces and numbers. `var1 = message[0]` stores the first letter in `var1` and `var2 = message[1]` the second in `var2`. Now you can access these names.